# Usage of will/would

Tags: will-would

The usage of will/would - The correct option is will. I am unable to understand that why  we shouldn't use "would" as this is a prediction being made and is not not a certain event that will surely take place in future.

> A wildlife expert predicts that the reintroduction of the caribou into
>   northern Minnesota **would/will** fail if the density of the timber
>   wolf population is greater than one wolf for every 39 square miles.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**conditionals**
Conditional sentences are usually grouped into four main types.

1-the zero conditional is used to talk about common states or events(form=if/when+present simple + present simple).
If she **knows** you well,she **is** more talkative.
We **say** hello when we **see** each other in the street.

2-the first conditionals is used to talk about possible future states or events (form=if/when + present simple /continuous + will/be going to).
If you **go** away to study,you'**ll meet** a Lot of people.
I'**m going to** start without him if he **doesn't come** soon.

3-the second conditional is used to talk about unlikely or imaginary states or events in the present or future( form= if + past simple /continuous + would/could/should/might).
If she **spoke** Spanish,she **could** apply for the job in Madrid.
They **would** leave their jobs and travel the world if they **had** the money.

With *be* , the second conditional uses *were* instead of *was* in formal context.

If I **was/were** good at languages , i'd learn Japanese.

4-the third conditional is used to talk about imaginary states or events in the past(form=if+ past participle + would/could/should/might+ have+ past participle).
If we **have studied** other cultures at school ,we **might have been** more confident about travelling.
If you **had arrived** in Japan three months ago,you **would have seen**
The cherry blossom.

*notice that when the *if clause* is the first in the sentence ,it is followed by a comma.There is no comma when the main clause come first
REFERENCE: Objective advanced

Comment: I got the above 3. Can you please confirm that it is never possible to have -> if+ present tense+ would/could/might?

Comment: We can never use 'would/could /might' with the present tense in conditional sentences.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please type the 4th one?

Comment: Ok, just a moment.

Comment: I' ve  rewritten the answer.however,you must know that there is a number of point about conditional sentence.